# Nested div in css grid coming outside parent div?

Tags: html, css

Nested div in css grid coming outside parent div. How can I fix it? I tried overflow: auto hidden but none of them is working on rightnested div. It is coming outside for small screen like mobile for desktop and iPad it is working fine.

code

```
<div class="projects-grid">
  <div class="leftnested">
    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
    <div>
      <img src={require('../assets/mobile app/Screenshot_3.png')}
      style={{objectFit: 'contain', height: 300}}
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src={require('../assets/mobile app/Screenshot_1.png')}
      style={{objectFit: 'contain', height: 300}}
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src={require('../assets/mobile app/Screenshot_4.png')}
      style={{objectFit: 'contain', height: 300}}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  <img
    alt="playstore"
    src={require('../assets/playstore.png')}
    style={{width: 150, height: 60}}
  />
</div>
</div>
<div class="rightnested">
  <p>Project content</p>
  <p>Project content asdasdghasgdhasgdhgahs
    sadajsdhjahsdjahjsda

  </p>
  <p>Project content asdasdghasgdhasgdhgahs
    sadajsdhjahsdjahjsda
    sajdajsdhkajhdjashdkja

  </p>
  <p>Project content asdasdghasgdhasgdhgahs
    sadajsdhjahsdjahjsda

  </p>
  <p>Project content asdasdghasgdhasgdhgahs
    sadajsdhjahsdjahjsda

  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.projects-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, auto));
  height: auto;
  margin: 25px;
}

.rightnested {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}

.leftnested {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k6Loujx1/

for small screen blue background div is coming outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
.projects-grid {
display: grid;
grid-gap: 1em;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, auto));
height: auto;
margin: 25px;}
```

replace

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, auto));
```

with

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, auto));
```

It's still gonna break on 200px width, but it should cover any mobile phone resolution.

Comment: Yes it works but lets say I add images in leftnested div then they are coming out how can I handle that as well? see screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/wAfbcxN

Comment: That would be because you're setting the image height to be 300px, which later forces the width to be larger than the conainer, you should control the size of the image with the width property instead of height, atleast on smaller screens.

Comment: how to handle width for small screens as well as large screens?

Comment: Well, i don't see a reason the image would look any worse if you just use the witdh: 100%, instead of the height for both screens, and if it doesn't look like you would like it on desktops you could use media queries to change the properties of the image on smaller screens.

Comment: ok I fixed the images. I added width: auto and height: 300 for parent div of each image and then for image I added width 100% and height 100% and it works like a charm